# sorting a collection in hibernate with an object value which could be null

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, collections

I have a hibernate class like this:

```
public class UserActivityLog implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;
private Users users;
private Servers servers;
private Date time;
private String event;
}
```

I sort a collection of UserActivityLog objects, using hibernate sorting. here's my hibernate criteria:

```
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(sortField, new Timestamp(startDate.getTime())));
    //add one day to the real end date for it to be considered in criteria
    Date eDate = getEndDate(endDate);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.le(sortField, new Timestamp(eDate.getTime())));
    if (searchByUser >= 0) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("users.id", searchByUser));
    }
    if (searchByHostId >= 0) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("servers.id", searchByHostId));
    }
    if (!searchByEvent.isEmpty()) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("event", searchByEvent, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    }


    if(sortColumn.equals("username")) {
        sortColumn = "users.username";
        criteria.createAlias("users", "users");
    }
    else if (sortColumn.equals("hostName")) {
        sortColumn = "servers.hostName";
        criteria.createAlias("servers", "servers");
    }
    //specify the sorting oder
    if(SortDirection.asc.equals(sortDirection)) {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(sortColumn));
    } else {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(sortColumn));
    }

    List<Object> allRows = (ArrayList<Object>) criteria.list();
```

The servers property of the UserActivityLog can be null. When the collection has an object with servers null, and if I sort the collection using hostName which is a property in the Servers object, the sorted collection does not contain that object with servers = null. Is there any reason for that or am I doing something wrong?

Update:
Here is the hibernate query:

```
select count(*) as y0_ from USER_ACTIVITY_LOG this_ inner join SERVERS servers1_ on    this_.HOST_ID=servers1_.ID 
where this_.TIME>='2014/9/16' and this_.TIME<='2014/9/25' order by servers1_.HOST_NAME asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found both the root cause and the solution:
When I inspect the hibernate query corresponding to this sort, it has an inner join with the Servers table (the query is shown in the question). When there's a log entry with the server = null, the join fails therefore that record is not displayed.

What I did to fix the issue is to force a LEFT JOIN for that sort column:

```
    if (sortColumn.equals("hostName")) {
        sortColumn = "servers.hostName";
        criteria.createAlias("servers", "servers", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the objects with servers = null is not been fetched from the database because of:

```
if (searchByHostId >= 0) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("servers.id", searchByHostId));
}
```

Not because of the sort.

Comment: I don't think so, because I did not set search criteria for host Id when sorting. Means that if (searchByHostId >= 0) condition was not true.

Comment: Also, initial data load sorts the collection by time by default. At this time, I can see the empty server object. Even when I sort by another column it's there. Only when sorted by the hostname, the issue occurs.

Comment: Well, it is not the sort. Sort don't remove any record from the result.

Comment: Post the underliyng SQL query... maybe it will help

Comment: added the hibernate query, at the same time I figured out the issue. When you sort from a foreign key property, the hibernate query creates an inner join to the foreign key table. Therefore you wont get that null record. Is there anyway to work around this with the criteria or do I have to execute an HQL?

Comment: Force corresponding left join when sorting the hostName.

Comment: can I do that using the criteria or do I have to use a query?

Comment: I found the following, but seems its deprecated:                            criteria.createAlias("servers", "servers",  Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);

Comment: To be honest, I hate criteria. I use HQL, because I feel it give me more control. Other matter, I avoid to make a method like this, with many possible options. Find out the ones users use the most and just do that.